Is it possible to find a general algorithm for determining how many models for a given theory there are?
In this context there already exists a model and the theory is consistent. I'm leaning towards no, because of Turing's Halting Problem and the fact that you should be able to mimic a Turing machine within model theory. How can I prove this though?
What if it is also given that there are guaranteed to be only finitely many models?

Deciding if there are 0 models or not is the same thing as deciding the consistency of the theory.

Please make the bodies of your MSE questions self-contained. Do not rely on the title to convey important information. As for the mathematics, see @spaceisdarkgreen's answer for the main point.

@RobArthan Why though? Surely the body is never viewed in a context where the title is not also present?

@spaceisdarkgreen Oh sorry I meant in the case that it is already established that the there is at least one model already.

@Adam: If you would like to read our site suggestions regarding titles, take a look here, and in particular scroll down to the heading Your question should be clear without the title.

Models are sets, so, if you give me finitely many models $M_1,...,M_k$ of a theory, I will pick some $x \not\in M_1 \cup\cdots\cup M_k$ and some $x' \in M_1$ (w.l.o.g. $M_1 \ne \emptyset$) and then I will define a new model $M_{n+1} = (M_1 - {x}) \cup {x'}$ (replacing $x$ by $x'$ as needed in the constant assignment function of the model $M_{n+1}$). So there are never "finitely many models".

As @LeeMosher says, please read the guidelines. I only read the title when I'm selecting the question. Then I read the body. There have been (and may well still be) MSE interfaces that don't display the maths in the title correctly. My tip is: compose the body first and then compose a title that gives a nice summary of what you want to know.

The question is badly underspecified, but here are a few things that can be said.

If a theory $T$ has any (non-empty) model $M$, then it has infinitely many models (in fact, a proper class of models!) since any $M'$ which is isomorphic to $M$ is a model of $T$. See Lee Mosher's comment. So to make the question meaningful, you really want to ask about the number of models up to isomorphism.

If a theory $T$ has an infinite model, then by Löwenheim-Skolem, it has models of arbitrarily large cardinality. So $T$ has infinitely many models (in fact, a proper class of models!) even up to isomorphism. So to make the question meaningful, you are either (Option 1) restricting attention to theories all of whose models have size at most $n$ for some finite $n$, or (Option 2) you need to ask about the number of models up to isomorphism of a fixed cardinality (for example, how many countable models up to isomorphism does $T$ have?). Option 2 has been studied extensively by model theorists.

You ask about an algorithm that takes as input a theory $T$. How do you intend for your algorithm to take a theory as input? Are you assuming $T$ is finitely axiomatizable?

As spaceisdarkgreen pointed out in the comments, already the question of whether a finitely axiomatizable theory $T$ is consistent (i.e., has more than $0$ models) is undecidable. You clarified "In this context there already exists a model and the theory is consistent". But that doesn't help avoid undecidability. Suppose we have an algorithm that takes as input a sentence $\varphi$ and if $\varphi$ is consistent returns "yes" if and only if $\varphi$ has more than one model up to isomorphism (if $\varphi$ is inconsistent, the algorithm can behave arbitrarily). I will show how to transform this into an algorithm to determine if an arbitrary sentence $\psi$ is consistent. We take $\psi$ as input. Now we form a new language by adding a new unary predicate symbol $P$ to the language of $\psi$. By a trivial structure, I mean a structure with one element $*$ such that every $k$-ary relation symbol in the language is true of the unique $k$-tuple $(*,*,\dots,*)$. Note that there is a sentence $\theta$ such that $M\models \theta$ if and only if $M$ is trivial.  Let $\varphi$ be the sentence $((\forall x\, P(x))\land \theta)\lor ((\forall x\, \lnot P(x))\land \psi)$. Then $\varphi$ is consistent (since any trivial structure is a model). And $\varphi$ has more than one model if and only if $\psi$ is consistent.


